# trying to do linear regression in Python, but for some reason column data type is set to string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression

The code tries to clean the data, drop unwanted rows/columns, and put everything into one DF. I get an warning that says:
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
return super().drop(

I get an error that says:
x = df_2020[[float('ORtg'), float('Pace'), float('eFG%'), float('TOV%')]]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ORtg'

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

team_abbreviations = ['MIL', 'IND', 'CHI', 'CLE', 'DET', 'BOS', 'BRK', 'TOR', 'PHI', 'NYK',
                  'MIN', 'OKC', 'DEN', 'POR', 'UTA', 'LAL', 'LAC', 'GSW', 'PHO', 'SAC',
                  'WAS', 'ATL', 'ORL', 'MIA', 'CHO', 'MEM', 'NOP', 'HOU', 'SAS', 'DAL']
df_holder = []
for i in team_abbreviations:
    url_main = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{}/2021/gamelog-advanced/'.format(i)
    dfs = pd.read_html(url_main, header=1)
    data = dfs[0]
    data.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 3': '@'}, inplace=True)
    data.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 18': 'NaN Col'}, inplace=True)
    data.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 23': 'NaN Col'}, inplace=True)
    data = data.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Rk'])
    data.drop(index=data[data['Date'] == 'Date'].index, inplace=True)

    # data.drop('Unnamed: 18')
    # data.drop('Unnamed: 23')

    data.insert(3, 'Team', i)
#
    data.columns = ['Rk','G','Date','Team', '@', 'Opp','W/L','Tm_Score','Opp_Score','ORtg', 'DRtg', 'Pace', 'FTr', '3PAr', 'TS%', 'TRB%',
                'AST%', 'STL%', 'BLK%', 'Nan Col', 'eFG%', 'TOV%', 'ORB%', 'FT/FGA', 'NaN Col', 'eFG%', 'TOV%', 'DRB%', 'FT/FGA']

    df_holder.append(data)

df_2020 = pd.concat(df_holder)
print(df_2020)

print(df_2020.dtypes)
x = df_2020[[float('ORtg'), float('Pace'), float('eFG%'), float('TOV%')]]
y = df_2020['Tm_Score']
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x, y)
print('Intercept: \n', regr.intercept_)
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose with this line

```
x = df_2020[[float('ORtg'), float('Pace'), float('eFG%'), float('TOV%')]]
```

you are attempting to convert column data from strings to floats. But that's not what this code does. You need

```
df_2020['ORtg'] = df_2020['ORtg'].astype(float)
df_2020['Pace'] = df_2020['Pace'].astype(float)
...
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. Do you know what I can do about the warning message?

Comment: No, I don't see what causes it. In case it is this line `data.drop(index=data[data['Date'] == 'Date'].index, inplace=True)` try replacing it with `data = data.loc[lambda x: x.Date != 'Date']`.

Comment: it caused by `data.drop(index=data[data['Date'] == 'Date'].index, inplace=True)`. But its only a warning to make you aware of what is happening. As long as you are getting the desired output, I would ignore it.